# Marklogic Property Search - XML Element array

Tags: marklogic

This is property file of a document in Marklogic

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prop:properties xmlns:prop="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property">
  <type type="string" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">document</type>
  <project type="string" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">Eagle</project>
  <fileroom type="string" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">Fileroom3</fileroom>
  <documentTitle type="string" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">HadoopOperations</documentTitle>
  <uploadDate type="string" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">2015-08-21T12:45:19.138Z</uploadDate>
  <lastModified type="string" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">2015-08-21T12:45:19.138Z</lastModified>
  <numPages type="number" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">11</numPages>
  <users type="array" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
    <item type="string">mreviewer1@merrill.com</item>
    <item type="string">madmin1@merrill.com</item>
  </users>
  <cpf:processing-status xmlns:cpf="http://marklogic.com/cpf">done</cpf:processing-status>
  <cpf:property-hash xmlns:cpf="http://marklogic.com/cpf">77ecfa8e87a5097e29b4d9846e131a67</cpf:property-hash>
  <cpf:last-updated xmlns:cpf="http://marklogic.com/cpf">2015-08-21T18:15:19.333+05:30</cpf:last-updated>
  <cpf:state xmlns:cpf="http://marklogic.com/cpf">http://marklogic.com/states/converted</cpf:state>
  <lnk:link from="/Eagle/Fileroom3/HadoopOperations_pdf_parts/" to="/Eagle/Fileroom3/HadoopOperations.pdf" rel="source" rev="conversion" strength="strong" xmlns:lnk="http://marklogic.com/cpf/links"/>
  <lnk:link from="/Eagle/Fileroom3/HadoopOperations_pdf.xhtml" to="/Eagle/Fileroom3/HadoopOperations.pdf" rel="source" rev="conversion" strength="strong" xmlns:lnk="http://marklogic.com/cpf/links"/>
  <cpf:self xmlns:cpf="http://marklogic.com/cpf">/Eagle/Fileroom3/HadoopOperations.pdf</cpf:self>
  <prop:last-modified>2015-08-21T18:15:23+05:30</prop:last-modified>
</prop:properties>
```

I want to write a query, where I need to find the documents where `users` property has "madmin1@merrill.com".

```
db.documents.query(
        qb.where(
                qb.directory(directories),
                qb.propertiesFragment(
                        qb.value(
                                qb.element(
                                        qb.qname("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic", "users")
                                ),
                                qb.term("admin.merrill.com")
                        )
                )
        ).withOptions({
            queryPlan: true,
            metrics:true,
            debug:true})
).result(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Output:

```
    [ { 'snippet-format': 'snippet',
    total: 0,
    start: 1,
    'page-length': 10,
    results: [],
    plan: { 'query-plan': [Object] },
    report: '(cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:and-query((cts:directory-query("/Eagle/Fileroom1/", "1"), cts:properties-fragment-query(cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic","users"), "admin.merrill.com", ("lang=en"), 1))), ()), ("unfiltered",cts:score-order("descending")), 1))[1 to 10]',
    metrics: 
     { 'query-resolution-time': 'PT0.015S',
       'snippet-resolution-time': 'PT0S',
       'total-time': 'PT0.172S' } } ]
```

But getting  empty array. Please help to correct this query.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for `admin.merrill.com`, while you say you want to find `madmin1@merrill.com`. Next to that you are searching the `jbasic:users` element, but with your approach you will be looking for a value match with the full string value of that element, which includes multiple mail addresses.

I would recommend adding a path range index for `jbasic:users/jbasic:item` (make sure to add the namespace as well), and use that for matching. You will need to switch to a path range query to leverage the index.

This could also give you a performance improvement. Range queries usually perform better than value queries..

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it si **qb.properties()** and **not** *qb.propertiesFragment()*

Source: https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/node-dev/search